# Regex Help need to pull NFL Team name from a string

Tags: c#, regex, string

I need to pull the NFL Team names from a string of different characters from data similar to below:

> &nfl_s_delay=120&nfl_s_stamp=1106052247&nfl_s_left1=Cleveland%20at%20Cincinnati%20(8:25%20PM%20ET)&nfl_s_right1_count=0&nfl_s_url1=http://sports.espn.go.com/nfl/preview?gameId=400554328&nfl_s_left2=Kansas%20City%20at%20Buffalo%20(1:00%20PM%20ET)&nfl_s_right2_count=0&nfl_s_url2=http://sports.espn.go.com/nfl/preview?gameId=400554332&nfl_s_left3=Miami%20at%20Detroit%20(1:00%20PM%20ET)&nfl_s_right3_count=0&nfl_s_url3=http://sports.espn.go.com/nfl/preview?gameId=400554355&nfl_s_left4=Dallas%20at%20Jacksonville%20(1:00%20PM%20ET)&nfl_s_right4_count=0&nfl_s_url4=http://sports.espn.go.com/nfl/preview?gameId=400554358&nfl_s_left5=San%20Francisco%20at%20New%20Orleans%20(1:00%20PM%20ET)&nfl_s_right5_count=0&nfl_s_url5=http://sports.espn.go.com/nfl/preview?gameId=400554362&nfl_s_left6=Tennessee%20at%20Baltimore%20(1:00%20PM%20ET)&nfl_s_right6_count=0&nfl_s_url6=http://sports.espn.go.com/nfl/preview?gameId=400554367&nfl_s_left7=Pittsburgh%20at%20NY%20Jets%20(1:00%20PM%20ET)&nfl_s_right7_count=0&nfl_s_url7=http://sports.espn.go.com/nfl/preview?gameId=400554370&nfl_s_left8=Atlanta%20at%20Tampa%20Bay%20(1:00%20PM%20ET)&nfl_s_right8_count=0&nfl_s_url8=http://sports.espn.go.com/nfl/preview?gameId=400554372&nfl_s_left9=Denver%20at%20Oakland%20(4:05%20PM%20ET)&nfl_s_right9_count=0&nfl_s_url9=http://sports.espn.go.com/nfl/preview?gameId=400554396&nfl_s_left10=St.%20Louis%20at%20Arizona%20(4:25%20PM%20ET)&nfl_s_right10_count=0&nfl_s_url10=http://sports.espn.go.com/nfl/preview?gameId=400554397&nfl_s_left11=NY%20Giants%20at%20Seattle%20(4:25%20PM%20ET)&nfl_s_right11_count=0&nfl_s_url11=http://sports.espn.go.com/nfl/preview?gameId=400554400&nfl_s_left12=Chicago%20at%20Green%20Bay%20(8:30%20PM%20ET)&nfl_s_right12_count=0&nfl_s_url12=http://sports.espn.go.com/nfl/preview?gameId=400554403&nfl_s_left13=Carolina%20at%20Philadelphia%20(8:30%20PM%20ET)&nfl_s_right13_count=0&nfl_s_url13=http://sports.espn.go.com/nfl/preview?gameId=400554408&nfl_s_count=13&nfl_s_loaded=true

I have tried this pattern:

```
string pattern = @"[^A-Za-z]";
```

However it doesn't return what I need. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Your regex is looking for a single non-letter character. You need to specify what you want it to find.

Comment: Did you actually make an attempt?  That regex makes no sense for this.

Comment: You really should make an honest attempt at it, otherwise you are just asking for people to do it all for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
(=[A-Z])(\w|\%20|\.)+
```

This will capture only the team names and the space characters between them, with leading "=". Then you can replace "%20" with " " and split the resultant string along "=" so you'll have a list of strings, each separately a team name. At least, that's what I'd do in Python. Not sure what methods are available to you.

Comment: Thank you for the help.....Im new at Regex and not really sure how it works...very confusing to a newbie.....with your help I was able to write a method to get the data I needed....